# Handlebars helper using uncompiled variables

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm trying to write a helper (or anything else that might work) to translate strings that includes uncompiled variables. I would love to continue using the block expressions `{{#i18n}}{{/i18n}}` for this, as I have harvesters using regexp set up.

So the problem is that `{{#i18n}}Hi {{ name }}{{/i18n}}` gets compiled into `Hi Bob` before it's being translated, and that becomes problematic and not scalable as you can imagine. I want it to first translate `Hi {{ name }}` and then compile it. I can't move the variable outside, as most other sentences are longer and variables are needed to get the context when our translators translate.

The helper I have now looks like this:

```
hb.registerHelper('i18n', function(options) {
    return i18n.__({phrase: options.fn(this), locale: language});
});
```

and then I compile and populate with data like this:

```
var compiled = hb.compile(layout.toString());
var html = compiled(templateData);
```

How can I solve this, preferably still using `{{#i18n}}{{/i18n}}`.